# I accidental went swimming with my iPod Touch 5th Generation

Tags: battery, ipod

Today, I went to a river and forgot that my iPod was in my pocket. I was in there for about half an hour, and only noticed it once I was changing into my other clothes. Is there anything I can do to fix it? Please help :(

Comment: there is not much you can do leave it in the sun to dry for few hours, that's all you can do.

Comment: put it in a bag of rice for a day or so.
And don't try turning it on until you are >99% sure it has dried

Comment: I tried them both. They didn't work. The iPod charges and gets hot but the screen stays black.

Answer (score 1):

This is the generally first aid when a device gets wet.

1. TURN IT OFF as fast as possible. Don't even think about turning it on again till you are very sure it is dry. Don't try charging or plugging it in. Water and power do not mix well.
2. While leaving it off and unplugged, stick it in a bag container with dry rice. Rice ascorbs moisture, and if there is any chance your device is not already broken beyond repair then it needs to be completely dry before any attempt is made to turn it on again.
3. leave it in the rice for a week or so.
4. Remove it from the rice, turn it back on and hope for the best. If you are lucky it might still work. If it doesnt Apple can sometimes fix things but as it is water damage it will have voided any warranty and it will be somewhat expensive.

In your case since you already tried to turn it while possibly still wet, there is a good chance the circuits have unfortunately already been fried, leaving going to Apple or another fixit company as one solution or buying a new device as the other.